# Power Automate Trigger Condition

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, power-platform

I have created a simple SharePoint list with two columns: job Number and comment. An email will send out if the job number is not null.
However, if the job number is not null and someone updates the list with a comment column, the email will trigger again. How can I fix this so that email only sends if the job number is not empty and does not look at other columns?

@not(equals(triggerBody()?['JobNumber'], null ))

[image]

Comment: Do you want to send an email only once for one list item (only once when JobNumber is updated to non null value)?

Comment: Yes, and if the list for the comment field is updated, then an email should not be sent out.

Comment: Hi Harris, any update on this thread? Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept my below response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Create one more column in the list (say `IsEmailSent`) and set default value to "No"
2. Add trigger condition based on this column along with the condition related to Job Number (You can add more than one conditions in trigger conditions section):

   ```
   @equals(triggerBody()?['IsEmailSent'],"No")
   ```
3. At the end of your flow (after Send an email action), add **Update item** action for same list item and update `IsEmailSent` to "Yes".
4. This will ensure that email notification is sent only once per list item